# Use of method calls vs channel

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I'm getting more familiar with Go's concurrency patterns and I want to clarify the best practices.

1. I understand that we want to use channels for the communication
   between goroutines. That being said are there cases where struct
   methods calls make sense or channels are to be used *in every
   situation*?
2. When communicating messages / struct that are processed
   (not modules that are passed around / registered etc.) is it better to pass
   them by value so that we don't risk to have two goroutines modifying
   it at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot communicate with another goroutine using method calls, or function calls. When you call a function from a goroutine, that function executes in the goroutine that called it. You can only communicate with another goroutine using channels, or by sharing memory and using synchronization primitives in the sync package to prevent race conditions.

The second part of the question depends on the situation.

```
g1:
y:=<-ch

g2:
ch<-x
```

In the above scenario, g1 and g2 are separate goroutines. Say, g2 sends the value (not pointer) x to g1. Then g1 gets a copy of x, and both goroutines can work on their copy. If x is a pointer, then g1 gets a pointer to x, and then g1 and g2 have to coordinate access to the value pointer to by that pointer.

So, if g2 does not read or modify the value x after sending it to g1, then it is fine to send the pointer to avoid copy.

Comment: *You can only communicate with another goroutine using channels* is not strictly accurate: you can also communicate through shared memory access. But if you do that, you will in general need to use a mutex.

Comment: Still not quite right - "or by shared memory using synchronization primitives in the sync package" is misleading. You share memory using pointers, not using `sync`. In order to avoid race conditions accessing shared memory, you need to synchronize that access using the `sync` package. Two separate things.

Comment: @BurakSerdar you definitely need pointers to share memory. How else would you have two goroutines reference the same memory?

Comment: @Adrian i:=0; go func() { i++}(); go func() { i--}